# What is the scientific name for an intelligent species that can breed with all other known intelligent species?

Tags: aliens, language, names

Ship log:

It has been a year since we discovered the alien species that now are dubbed Venusians. Our first impression was that all of them look like extremly beautiful human females. Our second impression was that they are EXTREMLY xenophile.

After a couple of months we learned that they somehow can get pregnant by both human males and females. Now of course we know they can get pregnant by every known intelligent species, be it humans, lizardmen, klingons, twi'lek, orks or elves. I feel we should give a scientific name to that ability, but these names are usually sort sort of neo latin/greek and neither the science officer nor me speak any latin or greek. So what is it called?

Comment: This is opinion based: names are conventions.

Comment: Scientific names follow certain rules, think of things like monogamy or polygamy or arachnophobia.

Comment: You know, Xenophile.

Comment: This seems like a simple Wikipedia query: The naming convention is called [binomial nomenclature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_nomenclature). Within that framework, your choice of name seems a matter of opinion.

Comment: This is simple enough. "Pangenic" or from the Greek, roughly speaking, "all-producing" or "all-making".Possibly, even "paneious" or "all-egg" or the capacity to breed, i.e., share eggs with all species. Whatever the Latin equivalents are they will begin "omni".

Comment: This question is logicaly inconsistent with the definition of the word "species".

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY nah, that just means they want to undergo that mating ritual with everyone else, not that they can actually produce offspring

Comment: *Panamatoria felsii* springs to mind...

Comment: Impossible imaginaris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple enough. "Pangenic" or from the Greek, roughly speaking, "all-producing" or "all-making".Possibly, even "paneious" or "all-egg" or the capacity to breed, i.e., share eggs with all species. Whatever the Latin equivalents are they will begin "omni".

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest "polyfertil". Please consider, that the ability to only breed with intelligent species is a bit far-fetched, since dna doesn't know how intelligent the resulting animal will be. We don't even know, if alien species use dna or some other type of blue print.

You could change that to "can breed with dna-based species", "can breed with humanoid species", "can breed with mammals", "can breed with vertebrate species" etc.

Edit: 
After reading the other answer, I realized that I misunderstood the question a bit. The "polyfertil" meant the property of being able to breed with many species. "Xenophile" means that they are attracted to foreigners.

The name of the species could be anything that comes into your mind. Like "Venusian vulgaris" or "Hominidus venusian". So the name doesn't even need to refer to their ability to mate with other species.

Answer (score 1):

First, we have a slight problem with “species”, since interbreeding ability is what makes two animal kinds into separate species (as opposed to 
breeds or races). But set that aside because your creatures are super special.

The binomial nomenclature ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_nomenclature ) requires the first name to be the general type of the species and the second name to be the specific name. A tautonymous name is one where both words are the same, used for extremely unique species or species that are the generic prototype that all others are compared against. In your case, I think a species that can interbreed so thoroughly means it can never speciate, so it will remain unique. So a tautonym is appropriate. So I would go with:

*Xenophile xenophile*

(Species names are always written in italics, with only the first word capitalized.)